# Send an email when a new record is created via admin generator

Tags: symfony1, notifications, admin-generator

I had used the symfony admin generator to create an web application for athletes management. One of the last client's requirement was to add a feature to notice the user and send an e-mail to the administrators when an athlete with the same number is inserted on the database. Until now, the column number of the Athlete table had a unique constraint but the client desires that the athlete can by inserted anyway.

To accomplish that, I was trying to extend the the edit / new actions in order to implement the client requirements.

Here is the code:

```
public function executeEdit(sfWebRequest $request)
    {
        $user = $this->getUser();

        if(! $user->hasCredential('admin'))
        {

            $clube_id = $user->getAttribute('id');
            $atleta_id = $request->getParameter('id');
            $atleta = Doctrine::getTable('Atleta')->find($atleta_id);

            if($clube_id != $atleta->clube_id)
                $this->forward404();        

        }

        if($request->get('post'))
        {
            // check if the inserted athlete BI already exists; if so, display a message to the user and send an email to the system admins
            $atleta_id = $request->getParameter('id');
            $atletaBIExiste = Doctrine::getTable('Atleta')->findDuplicateAthleteBI($atleta_id);

            if($atletaBIExiste)
            {
                // display a notice message to the user
                $this->getUser()->setFlash('error', 'Athlete already exists');

                // send an email to the system administrator
            }
        }


        return parent::executeEdit($request);
    }
```

Here is my problem: when I execute the edit action, I only want to check for a duplicate athlete number when the HTTP is POST but it seems that never is. I had already sent some exceptions to the output to verify which type is HTTP Request and it seems it is always GET.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you will be having is that when you hit save on the Edit page the information isn't posted to the edit action, it is posted to an action called update.

Have a look at the actions.class.php file in the cache and you will see it.

Comment: Hi there!

Thank you for the help!
Best regards!